# In Terraform, how can I define a list of objects?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

In Terraform, how do we define a list of objects?

**variables.tf**

```
variable "aws_cluster_arn" {
  type = string
  
}

variable "aws_ecs_placement_strategy" {
  type = list(object)
}
```

in **configuration.tfvars**

```
aws_ecs_placement_strategy=(object({type="spread",field="attribute:ecs.availability-zone"}),object({type="BinPack",field="CPU"}))
```

I am getting following error:

> Error: Invalid type specification
>
> on variables.tf line 53, in variable "aws_ecs_placement_strategy":
> 53:   type = list(object)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When defining an `object` type, you should specify all of the `object`'s fields and their types like so:

```
variable "aws_ecs_placement_strategy" {
  type = list(object({
     type = string,
     field = string
  }))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One often wants to be able to define a list of custom objects as variables in Terraform, and it's more straightforward than you'd think.

It can simply be defined as follows:

```
variable "var_name" {
   val_a = string
   val_list = list(object({
      list_val_1 = string
      list_val_2 = number
   }))
}
```

This way you can define a list of variable values that can be iterated through to generate resources dynamically. When paired with the 'dynamic' block, it becomes a a powerful tool. It can be used as follows, assuming we define a list of variables following the example above:

```
dynamic "resource_name" {
   for_each = var.var_name.val_list
   content = {
      val_1 = resource_name.value.list_val_1
      val_2 = resource_name.value.list_val_2
   }
}
```

Following this pattern can make your Terraform code much more modular and reusable, allowing for dynamic definitions that span multiple use cases.